# No instance for (Monad m0) arising from a use of `return'

Tags: qt, haskell

I try to create a program in haskell and Qt which displays in a graph some points got from an haskell function.

here is a working sample, but the point is in the return function and its parameters, not the rest of the code!

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    clazz <- newClass [
        defMethod' "factorial" (\_ txt ->
            let n = read $ T.unpack txt :: Integer
            in return . T.pack . show $ product [1..n] :: IO Text)]
    ctx <- newObject clazz ()
    runEngineLoop defaultEngineConfig {
        initialDocument = fileDocument "exemple4.qml",
        contextObject = Just $ anyObjRef ctx}
```

here is my code:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    clazz <- newClass [
        defMethod' "init_tableau" (\_  -> 
            return $ map (^2) [0..20])]
    ctx <- newObject clazz ()
    runEngineLoop defaultEngineConfig {
        initialDocument = fileDocument "exemple4.qml",
        contextObject = Just $ anyObjRef ctx}
```

it should only return the 21 first occurences of i^2, beginning from 0.

and here are all the errors:

```
Build FAILED

/home/lowley/Documents/haskell/Qt/lancer-qml4.hs: line 10, column 9:
  No instance for (MethodSuffix (m0 [b0]))
    arising from a use of defMethod'
  The type variables `m0', `b0' are ambiguous
  Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
  Note: there are several potential instances:
    instance (Marshal a, CanGetFrom a ~ Yes, MethodSuffix b) =>
             MethodSuffix (a -> b)
      -- Defined in `Graphics.QML.Objects'
    instance (Marshal a, CanReturnTo a ~ Yes) => MethodSuffix (IO a)
      -- Defined in `Graphics.QML.Objects'
  Possible fix:
    add an instance declaration for (MethodSuffix (m0 [b0]))
  In the expression:
    defMethod' "init_tableau" (\ _ -> return $ map (^ 2) [0 .. 20])
  In the first argument of `newClass', namely
    `[defMethod' "init_tableau" (\ _ -> return $ map (^ 2) [0 .. 20])]'
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    clazz <- newClass
               [defMethod' "init_tableau" (\ _ -> return $ map (^ 2) [0 .. 20])]
/home/lowley/Documents/haskell/Qt/lancer-qml4.hs: line 11, column 13:
  No instance for (Monad m0) arising from a use of `return'
  The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
  Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
  Note: there are several potential instances:
    instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
    instance Monad IO -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
    instance Monad [] -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
    ...plus two others
  In the expression: return
  In the expression: return $ map (^ 2) [0 .. 20]
  In the second argument of defMethod', namely
    `(\ _ -> return $ map (^ 2) [0 .. 20])'
/home/lowley/Documents/haskell/Qt/lancer-qml4.hs: line 11, column 27:
  No instance for (Num b0) arising from a use of `^'
  The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
  Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
  Note: there are several potential instances:
    instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
      -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
    ...plus three others
  In the first argument of `map', namely `(^ 2)'
  In the second argument of `($)', namely `map (^ 2) [0 .. 20]'
  In the expression: return $ map (^ 2) [0 .. 20]
/home/lowley/Documents/haskell/Qt/lancer-qml4.hs: line 11, column 31:
  No instance for (Enum b0)
    arising from the arithmetic sequence `0 .. 20'
  The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
  Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
  Note: there are several potential instances:
    instance Enum Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    instance Enum Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    instance Integral a => Enum (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
      -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
    ...plus 7 others
  In the second argument of `map', namely `[0 .. 20]'
  In the second argument of `($)', namely `map (^ 2) [0 .. 20]'
  In the expression: return $ map (^ 2) [0 .. 20]
```

I think the error is tiny, it should be quickly corrected but all my attempts were failures.

thanks you

EDIT:
for informations:

```
Prelude> let liste=[0..20] in map (^2) liste
[0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361,400]
Prelude>
```

I tried :

```
defMethod' "init_tableau" (\_  ->
            let a=map (^2) [0..20] 
            in return a)]
```

with roughly the same error

EDIT 2:

```
Prelude> :t map (^ 2) [0..20]
map (^ 2) [0..20] :: (Enum b, Num b) => [b]
```

EDIT 3:
with this code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    clazz <- newClass [ 
        defMethod' "init_tableau" (\_  -> 
            return ( map (^2) [0..20] ) :: IO [Integer] )]
    ctx <- newObject clazz ()
    runEngineLoop defaultEngineConfig {
        initialDocument = fileDocument "exemple4.qml",
        contextObject = Just $ anyObjRef ctx}
```

I've got this error:

```
/home/lowley/Documents/haskell/hsqml-demo-samples-0.3.4.0/qml/tableau1.hs:11:9:
    Couldn't match type `MarshalMode Integer ICanReturnTo ()'
                  with `Yes'
    In the expression:
      defMethod'
        "init_tableau"
        (\ _ -> return (map (^ 2) [0 .. 20]) :: IO [Integer])
    In the first argument of `newClass', namely
      `[defMethod'
          "init_tableau"
          (\ _ -> return (map (^ 2) [0 .. 20]) :: IO [Integer])]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      clazz <- newClass
                 [defMethod'
                    "init_tableau"
                    (\ _ -> return (map (^ 2) [0 .. 20]) :: IO [Integer])]
```

I still can't resolve it.

Comment: You should try breaking the expression `map (^2) [0..20]` out into its own definition, and that might make the error more clear. What type is that expression?

Comment: Have a look at the edit please

Comment: You've masked the error by typing it into `ghci`, which performs type defaulting. If you type `:t map (^ 2) [0..20]` into `ghci` that might help more.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but I suspect the problem here is that there are many appropriate monads that could be used. If you want to be completely parallel to the working example, you can explicitly choose to use `IO` as the monad by adding a type annotation to the `return` expression:

```
return $ map (^2) [0..20] :: IO [Integer]
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Wagner's suggestion fixes the error you asked about.

You now have another, unrelated error:

```
Couldn't match type `MarshalMode Integer ICanReturnTo ()' with `Yes'
```

Now consider the type

```
defMethod' :: (Typeable obj, MethodSuffix ms) => String -> (ObjRef obj -> ms) -> Member obj
```

You are attempting to pass `(\_  -> return ( map (^2) [0..20] ) :: IO [Integer] )` to that as the second argument.

So can we unify `ObjRef obj -> ms` with `forall a. a -> IO [Integer]`?

Well, the first part unifies because `a` is free. But is `IO [Integer]` an instance of `MethodSuffix`? Follow the typeclasses and you'll see this requires that `[Integer]` be an instance of `Marshal` and [follow that](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsqml-0.3.4.0/docs/Graphics-QML-Marshal.html#t:Marshal) and you'll see we can't do that. I didn't see a good listing of the basic instances of `Marshal` in the docs, but I did find them in the [source](http://hub.darcs.net/komadori/HsQML/browse/src/Graphics/QML/Marshal.hs#65).

So it seems if instead of `[Integer]` you try to return `[Int]` or `Text`, then this will likely typecheck.